# RegEx search & replace & casefold, but only in certain lines

Tags: xml, regex, sed

I have an XML file with lines like this:

```
<key>a_acute</key>
<string>a_acute.glif</string>
```

And I need to turn this into something like this:

```
<key>Aacute</key>
<string>a_acute.glif</string>
```

I.e. replace a letter followed by an underscore with the uppercase of the letter (leaving out the underscore), but only on lines starting with `<key>`. This is what I have so far:

```
sed '/^<key/s/\(.\)_/\1/'
```

This will drop the underscore on `<key>` lines. But I can't get it to casefold. I thought that putting a `\U` before the `\1` would do the trick, but it doesn't. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

1. As a general rule: don't use regular expressions to parse non-regular languages like XML.
2. `\U` is a feature of GNU sed, not available by default on Mac OS X. You can install it from [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) as `gnu-sed` or from [macports](https://www.macports.org/) as `gsed`.
3. If you don't want to rely on outside tools, you can do it with perl like this (with `-i` the file is changed in-place):

   perl -i -pe 's/(?<=)(.)_/\U$1/' file.plist